# wxScrolledWindow Refreshing with Zoom

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I use wxScolledWindow to load an image and then draw shapes on that image. The image is loaded using the *Fit option*, meaning the zoom level is adjusted according to the size of the image. I use `wxBufferedPaintDC` and already set the background style using `SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT);`.

The problem is when drawing the shape (line, rectangle, ellipse ...) or resizing or moving it around the Refresh does not happen so I end up with a drawing similar to the below-shown one:

[image: Happened during drawing the shape]

I realize the problem mostly happens when the zoom level is different than 100%. The painting is done with the following piece of code:

```
void CImageCtrl::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    if (!m_BMP.IsOk())
        m_BMP = wxImage(m_Image.cols, m_Image.rows, m_Image.data, true);

    wxBufferedPaintDC dc(this);
    SetScale(m_ZoomVal, m_ZoomVal);
    DoPrepareDC(dc);
    dc.Clear();

    dc.DrawBitmap(m_BMP, wxPoint(0,0));

    for (const auto& shape : CActiveObj::GetObjects(this))
        shape->Draw(&dc);
}
```

Here `m_BMP` is of type wxBitmap and `m_Image` is of type cv::Mat.

Erasing the background is:

```
void CImageCtrl::OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent& event)
{
    event.Skip();
}
```

Fitting the image:

```
void CImageCtrl::FitImage()
{
    ShowScrollbars(wxSHOW_SB_NEVER, wxSHOW_SB_NEVER);

    wxRect r = GetClientRect();
    int cw = r.GetWidth();
    int ch = r.GetHeight();

    int imgW = m_Image.cols;
    int imgH = m_Image.rows;

    m_ZoomVal = std::min((float)cw / imgW, (float)ch / imgH);

    Refresh();
}
```

I also tried wxAutoBufferedPaintDC and the result is pretty much the same (wxBufferendPaintDC seems to work better). I wonder what I might be missing.

I am using wxWidgets 3.2.1 on Windows 11 using MSVC.